# A bounded solution to the partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

A bounded solution to the partial differential equation $ \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+e^{-t} \ $  $ \ \text{is/are}$

$(i)$ $u(x,t)=-e^{-t}$,

$(ii)$ $ u(x,t)=e^{-x} e^{-t}$,

$(iii)$ $u(x,t)=e^{-x}+e^{-t}$,

$(iv)$ $u(x,t)=x-e^{-t}$.

**Answer:**

This is a non-homogeneous heat equation.

We know that $ t>0$.

The general solution of heat equation is

$u(x,t)=e^{-Ct} \sin (C^2 x) $ , where $ C$ is a constant.

Thus option $(i)$ is true because it satisfies the equation as well as it has the form of general solution.

**But I can not comment on other options.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that $u:\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}.$ Then observe that 
$$u(x,t)= -e^{-t}\text{ satisfies the heat equation and }u<0\text{ and so it is bounded.}$$
$$u(x,t)= -e^{-x}e^{-t}\text{ does not satisfy the heat equation.}$$
$$u(x,t)= e^{-x} + e^{-t}\text{ does not satisfy the heat equation.}$$
$$u(x,t)= x-e^{-t}\text{ satisfies the heat equation but so it is 
 not bounded.}$$

The key idea is to plug in the form of the function and see if it satisfies the PDE and is bounded.